# Listing mapped network directories in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, network-drive

How do I get all of the mapped network drives (shared ones) like the ones that a person would see in Windows Explorer?

That is,

- Network Places

  - Computer 1

    - Shared Folder
  - Computer 2

    - Shared Folder 1
    - Shared Folder 2

Is there a command or an API function that I can use to get at least the names of the computers and its folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good ready-to-use solution in *[Network Shares and UNC paths](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/networkshares.aspx)* (at [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)).

If you want to do it yourself, I think using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be the way to go.

Also check *[Mapped network drives cannot be listed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1898195/337294)* for more information.